# Superscalar design on SimpleScalar simulation

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-pipelines

I've learnt theoretically Computer Architecture at uni.However I can't wrap my head around it in practice. I am using Simple Scalar tool to simulate a benchmark program with configurable computer design option parameters such as number of floating units ,pipeline width , integer ALU , memory ports.  Having tried different parameter values , I am getting a better CPI value. Many questions came to my mind about the correlation and dependency of parameters between each other .Such as "Is there correlation between the memory ports and the pipeline width ?".

But I am confused about what criteria I should use to set the parameters .I would like to make an informed decision.Maybe I am missing something in theory and now having problem connecting the dots.

As a note. For my benchmark program , I can have some  simulation results .[image]

Comment: I may have a hunch what *pipeline depth* means: What *is* `pipeline width`?

Comment: @greybeard number of ALUs

Comment: the answer is simple: probably you missed the entire course